# Always Returning in Loop Error in my code, wondering what I need to do to fix it?

Tags: python, syntax-error

Assuming List[int] has already been imported, I was wondering what is wrong with the last four lines of code in this question. I am getting an error message whenever I try to run it that states **"[Line 11] This loop will only ever run for one iteration**". Apologies for the lack of terminology or knowledge (I'm new to python)

```
def divisible_by_7(lst: List[int]) -> bool:
    """Return True if and only if lst contains an element divisible
    by 7. Otherwise, return False.
    
    >>> divisible_by_7([4,8,21,6])
    True
    >>> divisible_by_7([1,2,8,9])
    False
    """
    for num in lst:
        if num % 7 == 0:
            return True
        return False
```

Comment: You have a loop. In the loop is a branch. One branch returns (exits the function, and therefore the loop), the other branch returns (same thing). So how can your loop ever loop?

Comment: `return False` shouldn't be in your for-loop, "indentation"

Comment: Just put `return False` on the same indentation level as `for num...`. Then, it will only run that line if you never `return True`.

Comment: Thank you guys! Appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

Just move the "return False" like this:

```
for num in lst:
    if num % 7 == 0:
        return True
return False
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning inside the loop that means on its first iteration python will encounter a breaking statment which is `return` and this is the reason you have to pull the return statement one tab back so it let's the iteration complete unless you are doing this on purpose then you don't really need the iteration to do so.

By functionality your code says if the any element is divisible by 7 then for you which means pulling the return statement back.

```
for num in lst:
    if num % 7 == 0:
        return True
return False
```